# How to configure ipython shortcuts?

Tags: ipython, config

I tried adding this to my ipython config

```py
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.shortcuts = [
    {
        "command": "IPython:auto_suggest.accept",
        "new_keys": ["c-z"],
    }
]
```

but then ipython complains that:

```
ValueError: Multiple shortcuts matching {'command': 'IPython:auto_suggest.accept'} found, please add keys/filter to select one of: [Binding(command=<function accept at 0x7f6fc3aa4ca0>, keys=['c-f'], condition='has_suggestion & default_buffer_focused & emacs_like_insert_mode'), Binding(command=<function accept at 0x7f6fc3aa4ca0>, keys=['right'], condition='has_suggestion & default_buffer_focused & emacs_like_insert_mode')]
```

The documentation is not exactly verbose on the topic, or I haven't found the right place to look ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"for a command that already has a shortcut you need to use `match_keys` instead of `new_keys`":

```
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.shortcuts = [
    {
        "command": "IPython:auto_suggest.accept",
        "match_keys": ["c-z"],
    }
]
```

see: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/14117

Comment: LOL, when I saw your answer, I got happy and went to my config. Then I realized my config already had this. Then I checked the issue you linked and well, it was me who wrote the answer there :D Totally forgot that I already had this solved, and completely forgot to post an answer here. So anyway, thanks for finding this and not leaving it unanswered!